# Sabre Error with HotelRateDescriptionRS VERIFY FORMAT ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE

Tags: sabre

When doing a HotelRateDescriptionRS I am getting the following error:

```
 <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
  <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-02-25T15:33:32-06:00">
   <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
    <stl:Message code="0">VERIFY FORMAT</stl:Message>
    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
   </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
  </stl:Error>
 </stl:ApplicationResults>
</HotelRateDescriptionRS></soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>
```

When passing in a specific rate plan candidate:

```
    <RatePlanCandidates>
        <RatePlanCandidate CurrencyCode="USD" DCA_ProductCode="J1KB93"/>
    </RatePlanCandidates>
```

If I just pass in just the RPH value:

```
    <RatePlanCandidates>
        <RatePlanCandidate CurrencyCode="USD" RPH="004" />
    </RatePlanCandidates>
```

I do get a valid response, but the response does not contain any DCA_Cancellation or RoomRate information.

I see some information about i-HRD in the documentation here: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/hotel/search/hotel_rate_description

Given that, do we even need information from HotelRateDescriptionRS to continue processing a reservation? Can I just skip this part if no information is returned and continue with a PassengerDetailsRQ and OTA_HotelResRQ?

HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ Request:

```
   <HotelRateDescriptionRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.2.0">
      <AvailRequestSegment>
      <GuestCounts Count="2"/>
      <HotelSearchCriteria>
         <Criterion>
            <HotelRef HotelCode="0111622"/>
         </Criterion>
      </HotelSearchCriteria>
      <RatePlanCandidates>
         <RatePlanCandidate CurrencyCode="USD" DCA_ProductCode="J1KB93"/>
      </RatePlanCandidates>
      <TimeSpan End="03-14" Start="03-10" />
      </AvailRequestSegment>
   </HotelRateDescriptionRQ>
```

HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ Request

```
      <HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="2.0.1">
         <AvailRequestSegment>
            <GuestCounts Count="2" />
            <HotelSearchCriteria>
                <Criterion>
                    <HotelRef HotelCode="0111622" />
                </Criterion>
            </HotelSearchCriteria>
            <TimeSpan Start="03-10" End="03-14" />
         </AvailRequestSegment>
      </HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned, this is most likely related to i-HRD functionality. If you need to have this feature for a requirement of your app, you can request that to be enabled for you to your Sabre account manager.

Regarding skipping HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ step, some rates do allow you to do so, while others require that you display them before selling. Those rates will return an error upon sell if you didn't previously display the rules.

Comment: If some properties require HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ, shouldn't i-HRD be enabled by default? This seems like an odd way of doing things.

Comment: No, because the most common workflow is OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ (HOT) / HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ (HOD) / HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ (HRD) / OTA_HotelResLLSRQ (0H).
Independent HRD is not needed if you follow these steps.

Comment: Understood, but I get nothing back for this hotels HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ using RPH...

Comment: You should always be able to retrieve the rules. Are you  getting any error message returned? 

<AvailRequestSegment>
                <RatePlanCandidates>
                    <RatePlanCandidate RPH="4" />
                </RatePlanCandidates>
            </AvailRequestSegment>